Searching for a part of a string using a regular expression
I have an array of strings that I iterate through in the for loop
I need to find strings that can have any value in the middle
Examples of strings
foo.bar.XXXX.rab.oof
any value can be used instead of XXXXX
any number of characters (letters and numbers) can be used instead of XXXX
I'm trying to figure out regular expressions, but it's not working yet
Pattern = Pattern.compile("foo.bar.(\w).rab.oof");
if (....){

//code 

}

please tell me in which direction to look for a solution

Will the string always have 4 periods/dots?

Perhaps a character class is what you're looking for? : foo\.bar\.([\d+]|[\w+])\.rab\.oof  . Correct me if I'm wrong.

Can you share anymore input examples?

Slight update to my earlier comment: foo\.bar\.([\d]{1,}|[\w]{1,})\.rab\.oof 

"any number of characters" --> (.*) || any number of "letters and numbers" (alphanumeric) --> (\p{Alnum}*) (and in a String you need double two backslashes to represent a single one: "(\\p{Alnum}*)" )

If foo.bar. and .rab.oof are really fixed strings at the start/end you can just use [a-zA-Z0-9]+ to match any number of letters and digits
Full example Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("foo\\.bar\\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\.rab\\.oof");
I added \\. to make sure only literal dots . are matched. Otherwise something like foo.bar also matches foojbar

But OP specified the XXXX is a placeholder for "letters and numbers", wouldn't your parenthesized clause match any valid characters unrestricted to letters and numbers?

Fair. Somehow I only registered any value can be used

To fix your current expression, you just need to add a quantifier to your capture group. However, the code you provided will result in a syntax error because you did not escape the backslash. Once you fix these issues, your code should resemble the following:
Pattern.compile("foo.bar.(\\w+).rab.oof");

This pattern will only work if the input string follows the format foo.bar.XXXX.rab.oof, where the first two parts will always be foo and bar, and the last parts will always be rab and oof.
A more universal approach would be to split the string based with a period delimiter and fetch the middle index:
String string = "foo.bar.baz.qux.quux";
String[] parts = string.split("\\.");
String middlePart = parts[Math.floorDiv(parts.length, 2)];
System.out.println(middlePart);

EDIT
I misread the original question. If you are expecting all the input strings to be the same with only the middle section being dynamic, the pattern you provided (when fixed according to my original answer) will suffice. The only caveat is that \w will match some special characters. You can specify specific character classes to get around this. Here's an example:
private static final Pattern INPUT_VALIDATOR;

static {
    String[] leadingWords = { "foo", "bar" };
    String[] trailingWords = { "rab", "oof" };

    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner("\\."); // Joins strings on a regex dot literal
    Arrays.stream(leadingWords).forEach(joiner::add);
    joiner.add("([a-zA-Z0-9]+)"); // Matches numbers and letters
    Arrays.stream(trailingWords).forEach(joiner::add);

    INPUT_VALIDATOR = Pattern.compile(joiner.toString());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "foo.bar.go12.rab.oof";
    boolean matches = isValid(test);
    System.out.println(test + "\t" + matches);

    test = "foo.bar.b@dvalue.rab.oof";
    matches = isValid(test);
    System.out.println(test + "\t" + matches);
}

public static boolean isValid(String string) {
    return INPUT_VALIDATOR.matcher(string).matches();
}

The output is:
foo.bar.go12.rab.oof    true
foo.bar.b@dvalue.rab.oof    false


I don't think \w is appropriate if only letters and numbers are wanted. As \w also matches underscore (_)

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("foo\\.bar\\.\\w+\\.rab\\.oof");

Explanation:
foo\.bar\.: Escapes the dots (.), which are special characters in regex. The dots are literal here.
\w+: Matches one or more alphanumeric characters (this will match your XXXX part).
\.rab\.oof: Escapes the dots and matches the literal part after XXXX.

I don't think \w is appropriate if only letters and numbers are wanted. As \w also matches underscore (_)
